# Vagrant Shell Provisioning of PHP 5.4 and NodeJS 5.x Not Installing Requested Versions

Tags: shell, ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, provisioning

I'm slowing trying to build up a LAMP stack in Vagrant on Ubuntu 14.04 that will have Apache 2.4, MySQL 5.5.46, PHP 5.4, with some extras like phpMyAdmin, the latest NodeJS, and Composer to mimic our production environment.

Setting up Vagrant itself appears quite easy referencing the docs, but I've never had to setup Apache, MySQL, etc; so provisioning and setting up the server is all new.  Typically I just used Xampp for our legacy projects, and an already configured VM in Homestead with Forge for our new projects using Laravel, but the legacy projects need a VM now to reduce maintenance issues between developer environments.  I've tried to learn Puppet, but right now I'm the most comfortable just using the shell provisioner in case anyone is wondering why I would use the shell provisioner that isn't idempotent unlike Puppet, Ansible, etc.

To keep it simple I wanted to just install small pieces at a time to know that the proper versions were installed and I could use them when I SSH into the VM.  So I tried to install PHP 5.4 and referenced several different guides on installing on [Ubuntu](http://tecadmin.net/install-apache2-mysql-php5-on-ubuntu-systems/#), as well as some [Gists](https://gist.github.com/asmerkin/df919a6a79b081512366), and [StackOverflow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts). Similarly I did the same for NodeJS and Composer.  But, the PHP version appears to be 5.5 when I run `php -v` instead of 5.4, and the NodeJS version is `0.10.x` instead of `5.x`, also there was an npm error during provisioning indicating the version of npm is out of date.  Composer is the only install that appears to be the correct version 1.0-dev.

I've included my provisioning script below, and below that my Vagrantfile, though the Vagrantfile setup appears to be okay.  Can anyone indicate what I'm doing wrong while trying to install PHP 5.4 and Node 5.x with npm?

**Provision.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# ---------------------------------------
#          PHP Setup
# ---------------------------------------

apt-get update
apt-get install -y python-software-properties
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable

apt-get update
apt-get install -y php5 php5-cli php5-fpm curl php5-curl php5-mcrypt php5-xdebug

# ---------------------------------------
#       Tools Setup
# ---------------------------------------

# Adding NodeJs PPA Repository
apt-get update
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -

# Installing nodejs and npm
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
apt-get install -y build-essential

# Installing Bower and Grunt
npm install -g bower grunt-cli

# Installing GIT
apt-get install -y git

# Install Composer
curl -sL https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

# Make Composer available globally
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**Vagrantfile**

```
# Prevent TTY Errors
config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"

# Allow SSH Agent Forward from The Box
config.ssh.forward_agent = true

hostname = settings['hostname'] ||= 'LAMP'

# Use Latest Ubuntu 14.04 Box Version And Default Hostname Unless Overridden
config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
config.vm.box_version = '>= 0'
config.vm.hostname = hostname

network_ip = settings['ip'] ||= '192.168.33.33'

# Use Default IP Unless Overridden
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: network_ip

# Use Default Memory And CPUs Unless Overridden
config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|

  # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine:
  vb.gui = false

  # Customize the name of the VM:
  vb.name = hostname

  # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--memory', settings['memory'] ||= '2048']

  # Customize the number of CPUs on the VM:
  vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cpus', settings['cpus'] ||= '1']
end

# Default Port Forwarding
default_ports = {
    80 => 8888,
    443 => 44300,
    3306 => 33060,
    5432 => 54320
}

default_ports.each do |guest, host|
  config.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: guest, host: host, auto_correct: true
end

# ---------------------------------------
# Provision the box with the included software
# ---------------------------------------

config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'vagrant/scripts/provision.sh'
```

**UPDATE**

To figure out the distrib and version I SSH into the server and ran `cat /etc/*{release,version}` which indicated it was CentOs 6.7 (Final), which contains PHP 5.4, but lacks an official Vagrant box.  Also, `sudo apt-get ...` doesn't work and I need to use `yum` now? which isn't installing PHP 5.4 or anything else.

Comment: I'm curious. Is there a specific reason why you want to install PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04? The default versions, as you know, are 5.5 and 2.4 respectively.

Comment: Hi @PatrickLee, I'm trying to prevent errors in master with regards to PHP versioning, for example putting non-variable parameters into empty(), which aren't caught until they are committed and pushed to the test server since locally the devs are using 5.6 or now 7 for all our current projects.  It seems to be consuming a lot of time finding small errors like this which could be avoided if we just force PHP 5.4 for these legacy projects since we aren't able to update the production server.  As for Apache I don't really care which version so using Apache 2.4 is absolutely fine.

Comment: Hi @PatrickLee, actually I didn't know those were the default versions.  I don't use Linux distribs at all except in Laravel Homestead and that's only been in the last year.  So if I drop down to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS would this solve all my issues?  Or will that cause upgrading issues seems like that isn't even the default for the distrib.

Comment: Actually Ubuntu 12.04 would give you PHP 5.3. Ideally you would build your Vagrant VM using the same OS version you have in production. Is your production server running Ubuntu? And if so, which version?

Comment: Hi @PatrickLee, thanks I'm just trying to figure that out.  We have access to the control panel and all it says is Operating System Linux and lower down Kernel Version 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64, which I'm not sure if that's related.  I tried to SSH into the server, but got an error port 22: Connection timed out.  Will keep trying.

Comment: I searched for that kernel version and the results were nearly all RedHat or CentOS. That's not definitive evidence, but I'm guessing your server is running an RPM-based distro. Pretty sure that `el6` in the kernel version refers to Enterprise Linux 6, so that would mean either RedHat 6 or CentOS 6.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLee, I found PHP 5.4 as a default on CentOs 6.7 according to this site (https://webtatic.com/packages/php54/).  Will try that first.  Looking at Hitachi Vagrant Atlas though there's no officially maintained box for either, just a bunch of community boxes, which is too bad.